# How can I populate and submit a Google form using info from Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm new to Google script editor and not sure how to go about this. I have a group of people filling out referrals through the Google Form "A", and I would like to use the output of these forms to populate answers to (and auto-submit) the form "B". Can I take the new answers from the "A" response sheet and trigger a new submission of form "B" with all of the relevant information filled in? Is it possible to link forms in such a way?

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old post but this answer is for anyone else looking for the same solution to a similar problem quite recently. I did something similar recently- auto populating & auto updating a google form with data values from the google sheet after a response has been submitted, here is the working live sample form: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/48344518?hl=en